# how to express a uniform distribution with brownian motion (stochastic calculus)

Tags: stochastic-calculus

I'd like to express a uniform distribution $U[0,1]$ as a function of a Brownian motion $w(t)$.

Specifically, I am thinking about this problem in two versions of model setups.

Model setup version 1 is:
The total income of the society follows a geometric Brownian motion: $d \delta_t = \delta_t \mu_\delta dt + \delta_t \sigma_\delta dw_t$. There are two agents in the society, and their share of the total income at each period is: $z_t \times \delta_t$ and $(1-z_t) \times \delta_t$, where $z_t \sim Uniform[0,1]$.
However, I would like to express $z_t$ using a stochastic term (i.e., Brownian motion term) --- as opposed to a draw from a uniform distribution.

Model setup version 2 is:
suppose there are two groups of income in the society -- $h$ and $l$. The transition probability from $h$ to $l$ is $p_{hl}$, from $h$ to $h$ is $p_{hh}$. And $p_{hl} + p_{hh}$ = 1.
Suppose the agent's income at $t=0$ is $h$, then at $t=1$, his probability of arriving at $h$ is $p_{hl}$ and his probability of arriving at $l$ is $p_{hl}$. However, I would like to write his income at $t=1$ explicitly at $t=0$: something like $d y_t = y_t \mu_t dt + y_t \sigma_y dw_t$ (which is obviously not correct given the context), rather than two possible outcomes with probabilities.

I hope my question is clear. Please feel free to ask clarifying question, or to propose alternative model setups.

Thank you!

Best,

Darcy

Comment: note that $F^{-1}(U[0,1]) \sim W_t = N(0,t)$ so $F(W_t) \sim U[0,1]$ where $F$ is the CDF of $N(0,t)$

Comment: Thank you so much! Very helpful. Super grateful!